# In Python, how can I run a module that's not in my path?

Tags: python, pycharm, pythonpath

I'm using PyCharm, and in the shell, I can't run a file that isn't in the current directory. I know how to change directories in the terminal. But I can't run files from other folders. How can I fix this? Using Mac 2.7.8. Thanks!

Comment: why not just open the file in pycharm and run it or are you trying to import some functions from one file to another?

Answer (score 1):

Add a string containing the path name of the directory to 'sys.path', from the `sys` module. you should be able to import after that.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/directory')
import whatever
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to solve this.

1. In PyCharm go to Run/Edit Configurations and add the environment variable PYTHONPATH to $PYTHONPATH: and hit apply. The problem with this approach is that the imports will still be unresolved but the code will run fine as python knows where to find your modules at run time.
2. If you are using mac or unix systems. Use the command "EXPORT PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:". If Windows, you will have to add the directory to the PYTHONPATH environment variable.
3. This is as plarke suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `imp` module:

```
import imp
file, filename, otherStuff = imp.find_module( moduleName,  [ '/search/in', '/these/directories' ] )
imp.load_module( moduleNameOrAlias, file, filename, otherStuff )
```